# Can I Number a GroupTemplate or ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, paging

I would like to use a GroupTemplate to separate a list of items into groups.  However, I need each Group to be numbered sequentially so I can link to them and implement some JS paging.  I'm binding to an IEnumerable

Here's some pseudo code. I would like the output to look like this:

```
<a href="#group1">Go to Group 1<a>
<a href="#group2">Go to Group 2<a>
<a href="#group3">Go to Group 3<a>

<ul id="group1">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<ul id="group2">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<ul id="group3">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Is this easy to do in a ListView, using GroupTemplate and ItemTemplate?

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceholder">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <ul id="<!-- group-n goes here -->">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ul>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I can get the number of groups to do the links at the top from the Datasource and basic math, but how do I get **id="groupN"** number into the template?

Comment: Which is the SQL and group field ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can DataBind the id, so I'd probably either use a hidden field, have JQuery count them up, or use the CssClass. You can use `Container.DataItemIndex` to get your number.

Edit: By just changing the `ul` to be runat="server", ASP.NET will generate a unique id for you in it's infamous INamingContainer format. That will include an index as well, though it'll be something like `lv_ctrl0_group`, and is an implementation detail.

You could hook a handler to the `ul`'s Init event and append a number to it, making it something like `lv_ctrl0_group1`. I don't think you can get rid of the prepended INamingContainer stuff very easily, and this would probably break any IPostDataHandler controls.

```
<script runat="server">
    void Group_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       ((Control)sender).ID += groupId++.ToString();
    }
    int groupId = 0;
</script>

<asp:ListView id="lv" runat="server" GroupItemCount="3">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="groupPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <ul id="group" runat="server" oninit="Group_Init">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
        </ul>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Well, I was thinking of doing it all in jQuery, but it's not so much the count I need. I need a unique ID for each group. Can't use the class, because the links above reference those IDs (for accessibility and in-page links)

Container.DataItemIndex is a good idea, though.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing it this way. I want to preferably control the name of the IDs. It's easier to code the same-page links. I'm using the JQuery UI Tab Ctrl which take pagelinks & IDs and turns them into Tab-head and Tab-body respectively. So, I need to reference those IDs reliably.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the UI Tab Ctrl specifics, but you should be able to use JQuery to dynamically find the id's by looking for UL's (of a certain class or whose id's contain (*=) "group").

Answer (score 1):

In your aspx file:

```
<GroupTemplate>
  <ul id='<%# "group"+GroupNumber %>'>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
  </ul>
</GroupTemplate>
```

In your code behind (assuming C#):

```
int _GroupNumber=0;

protected string GroupNumber
{
   get { return (++_GroupNumber).ToString(); }
}
```

Comment: Great Simple solution and it would be great if it worked.  But the Group Property never gets called from the ListView.

Comment: Huh. Must not be part of the databinding process. How about <%# "group"+GroupNumber %>?

Comment: I found out that it doesn't databind the GroupTemplate.  Doesn't really work, unfortunately. I am trying to avoid splitting the data into a lists of lists and doing Nested ListViews. I need the IDs.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Keltex above would work with a small change; use **<%=** instead **<%#**,

**<%#** wouldnt work because GroupTemplate doesnt support databinding