# Access GroupTemplate Index in ListView control

Tags: asp.net, listview, indexing

I'm using a `ListView` control to group items, so that the page can display 5 items, and I need to pyut the group index as a class.

How can I access the index of the index of the groups, like I can with the items? I'm looking to do something like the following:

```
<GroupTemplate>
    <div class='<%# container.groupindex %>'>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
</GroupTemplate>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching around SO I found this answer to another question:

[Can I Number a GroupTemplate or ItemTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675474/can-i-number-a-grouptemplate-or-itemtemplate/679221#679221)

This has solved my problem, if a bit untidy.

If anyone knows a neater way I'm willing to accept.